# I continue to get a truncation error when trying to import a pipe delimited CSV into ssms

Tags: database, ssms

[image]

I am having some trouble loading a flat file into a database as a table using the wizard.

I keep getting a truncation error no matter if I change the type to varchar to max, change the type to a string, as well as set it to ignore truncation in the import wizard. I'm not sure if I'm missing something or what, as well as I'm not sure if this matters, but I receive a pipe delimited file for this import that's a CSV.

It continues to error on one row (row 55) but the length of the data in question is 59.

I tried expanding the length of the varchar to max, changing it to text, and also ignoring the truncation.

Comment: Please do not post images of code or errors. Text is preferred so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.